# Add a filter parameter to ssrs report

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that I need to update to allow user to filter out pending applications. I have created the parameter and tried to implement using case but it is not working or giving any error messages on how to correct it. The code is:

```
select distinct pers.person_fname,
                pers.person_mname,
                pers.person_lname,
                le.nationalprovidernumber NPN,
                lic.licensenumber         LICENSE_NUMBER,
                adr.address_line1         ADDRESS1,
                adr.address_line2         ADDRESS2,
                adr.address_line3         ADDRESS3,
                adr.city                  CITY,
                sp.state_province_name    STATE,
                adr.postal_code           ZIP_CODE,
                eml.email,
                rtp.residencetype_name    RESIDENCY,
                ltp.licensetype_name      LICENSE_TYPE,
                lic.expirationdate        DATE_OF_EXPIRATION
  from odilic_admin.license lic
  inner join odilic_admin.licenseststimeline lst
  on lic.license_id = lst.license_id
  inner join odilic_admin.licenseststype lstp
  on lst.licenseststype_id = lstp.licenseststype_id
  inner join odilic_admin.licensedef ldef
  on lic.licensedef_id = ldef.licensedef_id
  inner join odilic_admin.licensetype ltp
  on ldef.licensetype_id = ltp.licensetype_id
  inner join odilic_admin.residencetype rtp
  on ldef.residencetype_id = rtp.residencetype_id
  inner join odilic_admin.licensingentity le
  on  lic.licensingentity_id = le.licensingentity_id
  inner join odilic_admin.individual ind
  on le.licensingentity_id = ind.licensingentity_id
  inner join odidir_admin.person pers
  on ind.person_id = pers.person_id
  left outer join odidir_admin.person_address_rel par
  on pers.person_id = par.person_id
  left outer join odidir_admin.address adr
  on par.address_id = adr.address_id
  left outer join odidir_admin.address_type atp
  on adr.address_type_id = atp.address_type_id
  left outer join odidir_admin.state_province sp
  on adr.state_province_id = sp.state_province_id
  left outer join
       (select pr.person_id, em.email_id, em.email
          from odidir_admin.person           pr,
               odidir_admin.person_email_rel pe,
               odidir_admin.email            em
         where pr.person_id = pe.person_id
           and pe.email_id = em.email_id
           and email_type_id = 2) eml
  on pers.person_id = eml.person_id
 where 
 ltp.licensetype_id in (:License_type)
 and lstp.licenseststype_name = 'Active'
 and atp.address_type_name = 'Mailing Licensing'
 and (lic.expirationdate >= current_date and
 trunc(lic.expirationdate) = :Expiration_Date)
 and sysdate between lst.periodbegindate and lst.periodenddate
 order by lic.licensenumber
```

In order to get applications that are pending I need to access the table odilic_admin.licenseappl and filter out all licenses with appststype = 2 (pending). To do this I added a join to the query before the last left outer join andt hen a case at bottom for when this parameter is selected.

```
select distinct pers.person_fname,
                pers.person_mname,
                pers.person_lname,
                le.nationalprovidernumber NPN,
                lic.licensenumber         LICENSE_NUMBER,
                adr.address_line1         ADDRESS1,
                adr.address_line2         ADDRESS2,
                adr.address_line3         ADDRESS3,
                adr.city                  CITY,
                sp.state_province_name    STATE,
                adr.postal_code           ZIP_CODE,
                eml.email,
                rtp.residencetype_name    RESIDENCY,
                ltp.licensetype_name      LICENSE_TYPE,
                lic.expirationdate        DATE_OF_EXPIRATION
  from odilic_admin.license lic
  inner join odilic_admin.licenseststimeline lst
  on lic.license_id = lst.license_id
  inner join odilic_admin.licenseststype lstp
  on lst.licenseststype_id = lstp.licenseststype_id
  inner join odilic_admin.licensedef ldef
  on lic.licensedef_id = ldef.licensedef_id
  inner join odilic_admin.licensetype ltp
  on ldef.licensetype_id = ltp.licensetype_id
  inner join odilic_admin.residencetype rtp
  on ldef.residencetype_id = rtp.residencetype_id
  inner join odilic_admin.licensingentity le
  on  lic.licensingentity_id = le.licensingentity_id
  inner join odilic_admin.individual ind
  on le.licensingentity_id = ind.licensingentity_id
  inner join odidir_admin.person pers
  on ind.person_id = pers.person_id
  left outer join odidir_admin.person_address_rel par
  on pers.person_id = par.person_id
  left outer join odidir_admin.address adr
  on par.address_id = adr.address_id
  left outer join odidir_admin.address_type atp
  on adr.address_type_id = atp.address_type_id
  left outer join odidir_admin.state_province sp
  on adr.state_province_id = sp.state_province_id
  **left outer join odilic_admin.licenseappl appl
  on lic.licensingentity_id = appl.licenseappl_id**
  left outer join
       (select pr.person_id, em.email_id, em.email
          from odidir_admin.person           pr,
               odidir_admin.person_email_rel pe,
               odidir_admin.email            em
         where pr.person_id = pe.person_id
           and pe.email_id = em.email_id
           and email_type_id = 2) eml
  on pers.person_id = eml.person_id
 where 
 ltp.licensetype_id in (:License_type)
 and lstp.licenseststype_name = 'Active'
 and atp.address_type_name = 'Mailing Licensing'
 and (lic.expirationdate >= current_date and
 trunc(lic.expirationdate) = :Expiration_Date)
 and sysdate between lst.periodbegindate and lst.periodenddate
**case :pending when  = yes then appl.applststype_id !=2
end**
 order by lic.licensenumber
```

Instead of the case I have also tried using an IF with the same result. This looks like:

```
if :Pending = 1
then
 and appl.applststype_id != 2;
end if;
```

Any help to get me past this is greatly appreciated and I will be sure to vote and select most correct answer to help me solve this.

Comment: Oracle SQL running in ssrs

Comment: I disagree, it has everything to do with SSRS because of its use of report parameters.

Comment: Can one person have more than one licence application? If so, do you want to exclude people with *any* licence application pending, or only those people with *all* licence applications pending?

Comment: Each person can have more than one application by license type which is also a parameter.

Comment: The query works fine I just cant get the conditional filtering out of pending applications. I have tried IIF(), Case, and PLSQL IF with no luck.

Comment: So, do you want to exclude **people** with any licence application pending, or only the **licence applications** that are pending (conditional on the parameter in either case)?

Comment: Also, is `:pending` a string parameter (implied by your `case` condition) or a numeric parameter (implied by your `if` condition)?

Comment: It is an SSRS numeric parameter that asks Exclude Pending, Yes or No. With 1 being yes and 0 being no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `:pending` parameter is a numeric where a value of 1 indicates that pending licences are to be excluded and you only want to exclude **licence applications** that are pending, try adding the following condition in place of your existing `case` clause:

```
and (:pending <> 1 or appl.applststype_id !=2)
```

Comment: I was using a boolean parameter.  Let me switch up this parameter and I will get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Shouldnt pending be 0 instead of 1? The parameter is Excluding pending yes or no. With 1 being yes and 0 being no.

Comment: @BWoods: No - the condition here is saying "select values where *either* we are not excluding pending records (`:pending <> 1` - could also be represented as `:pending = 0`) *or* the application type is not pending (`appl.applststype_id != 2`)". It's the equivalent of `NOT (:pending = 1 and appl.applststype_id =2)`.